# Calculate velocity of bouncing objects with mass (Linear)

Tags: linear-algebra, game-physics

How do I calculate velocity for bouncing objects with mass?
[image]

```
f1 = ( (m1-m2)/(m1+m2) )*v1 + ( (m2*2 )/(m1+m2) )*v2
f2 = ( (m1*2 )/(m1+m2) )*v1 + ( (m2-m1)/(m1+m2) )*v2
```

Doesn't work if both objects collide while heading in the same direction

Any help will be appreiciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an maths problem, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1):

For 1d objects

v<sub>1</sub> = (u<sub>1</sub>(m<sub>1</sub>-m<sub>2</sub>) + 2m<sub>2</sub>u<sub>2</sub>)/(m<sub>1</sub>+m<sub>2</sub>)

v<sub>2</sub> = (u<sub>2</sub>(m<sub>2</sub>-m<sub>1</sub>) + 2m<sub>1</sub>u<sub>1</sub>)/(m<sub>1</sub>+m<sub>2</sub>)

Where v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> are the velocities after and u<sub>1</sub> and u<sub>2</sub> are velocities before, with m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> being the mass of each.

Which is the same but simplified version of the formula you have given. BTW your the code block has an error on line 1 5th var is `b2` should be `m2`

This will give the correct velocities if the bodies are moving in the same direction. All I can think that you may be doing wrong is not including the sign. If two bodies are moving in the same direction then the two velocities input u<sub>1</sub> and u<sub>2</sub> will have the same sign. For all other collisions they will each have a different sign.

If you are applying the above in a 2D situation you will need to modify the formula. This is the solution for circles where the point of contact is along the angle 'p' between them.

```
//
//      u1 * cos(d1 - p) * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * u2 * cos(d2 - p)
//V1x = -------------------------------------------------------- * cos(p) + u1 * sin(d1 - p) * cos(p + PI / 2)
//                           m1 + m2

//      u1 * cos(d1 - p) * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * u2 * cos(d2 - p)
//V1y = -------------------------------------------------------- * sin(p) + u1 * sin(d1 - p) * sin(p + PI / 2)
//                           m1 + m2
```

And do the same for the other object

- v1x,v1y are the resulting x,y components of the velocity
- u1,u2 is velocity.
- m1, m2 is the mass
- d1 , d2 us the direction of movement in radians.
- p is the angle of contact. This is the angle from the center of first
  object to the center of second object and the point of contact is on
  the line this angle describes.